# How to pass object inside React Navigation Navigator root Screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass data (object) inside Navigator Stack to root Screen, but in js component its become undefined. Please need your help, what I am dooing wrong?

So, in my App.js I have a state:

```
const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false); /// in code deeper it transformed to 'true'
```

this state I pass like object from App.js to a navigation component navigate.js in such way:

```
 <TabNavigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn}/>
```

Then in my Tab Navigation I recieve data in such way:

```
export default function TabNavigation({isSignedIn}) {...
```

Pass it to Stack Screen:

```
<Tab.Screen name="My Account" children={()=><AccountStackScreen isSignedIn={isSignedIn}/>} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: () => (<Image source={require("./assets/icon-assets/account.png")} style={{width: 28, height: 28}} />)
                }}/>
```

recive it in Stack Screen:

```
const AccountStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AccountStackScreen({isSignedIn}) {

    console.log({isSignedIn}) /// display Object {"isSignedIn": true,}
```

And finally, when I am trying to pass this object to Account.js component, it become undefined:

```
return (
        <AccountStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#FEE6E9',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: '#444444',
            },
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            headerShadowVisible: false,
        }}>
            <AccountStack.Screen 
                name='Account'
                component={Account}
                options={{title: 'My Account'}}
                isSignedIn={{isSignedIn}}
            />
        </AccountStack.Navigator>
    )
```

The result of displaing in Account.js component:

```
export default function Account({isSignedIn}) {
    console.log({isSignedIn}) /// display - Object {"isSignedIn": undefined,}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass props while navigating to desired screen or else you can use Context API

For Example:
if you want to pass props from Home Screen to Account Screen,

You can use

```js
onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('Account', {
        isSignedIn
    });
}}
```

Comment: Account Screen is a root screen in Account Tab, so I am not pass anything from Home Screen to Account screen, because they are both root Screens, but in different tabs

Answer (score 0):

Find a decision in react navigation documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#initial-params

The final decision is looks like (in navigation.js):

```
<AccountStack.Screen 
                name='Account'
                component={Account}
                options={{title: 'My Account'}}
                initialParams={{isSignedIn, login}}
            />
```

Where the main magic in **initialParams**

And recieve data in component Account.js:

```
export default function Account({route, navigation}) {...
var data = route.params.isSignedIn;
```

Where the main magic in **route** and **route.params.isSignedIn**